# animation loading bar using jquery or java

Tags: java, jquery

I have a pretty simple code here: http://jsfiddle.net/Pvp6Z/
And I'm trying just to add a simple `loading bar` that display when the browser is loading the code, something like that for example: http://ui-cloud.com/res/designmoo/Loading_bar/previews/main.png
or maybe something simpler.
I googled that trying to search for a code that help me doing that but haven't found anything, I think this will be done by using jquery or java, just wondering how can I do it.
NOTE: I will not use this bar for the code posted in the fiddle, I will run it for a heavier code that take some second to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/7K64g/)

```
var loading = function(){
    docHeight = $(document).height();

    $('body').append('<div class="overlay" style="background:#fff;width:100%;height:' + docHeight + 'px;position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;"></div>');

    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
      height: 150,
      modal: true
    });
};

loading();
```

I used some very basic jQuery UI to accomplish the loading. Then since I am not actually loading any content into the page, I used a setTimeout to simulate the wait. Once the wait is complete, it overwrites the loading GIF with whatever message you want to display using the ".html" method.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#dialog-modal").html('<p>Loading Complete</p>');
    $('.overlay').remove();
}, 3000);
```

Just run these 2 parts at the end of your script to close the loading overlay.

```
$("#dialog-modal").html('<p>Loading Complete</p>');
$('.overlay').remove();
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Wow it's a great code but there's something missed here, first of all I want it to prevent user from showing the page until the whole code are loaded, secondly I want it to stop loading and give the message "Loading Completed" **after the code is really loaded and completed loading**, not by setTimeout, is that possible?

Comment: What is the code that will be running in the background? Is it page load type stuff, or ajax requests? Any more info would be very helpful.

Comment: it doesn't really matter which type of code, what matter is to preview **only** a loading bar until the html,css code is loaded

Comment: something like that will be helpful?
http://forums.asp.net/t/1651666.aspx?+Show+Progress+Bar+while+loading+page

Comment: Updated the fiddle and answer.

Comment: That's better, can you make a change on the code so it hide the loading bar when the load is completed? so it doesn't show the message "loading completed"

Comment: Sure just replace the .html method with $("#dialog-modal").dialog('close');

Comment: great, that's perfect, thank you very much.
Only one last thing I would like to ask you about, can I remove the SetTimeout and stop the loading just when the code is loaded?

Comment: Yes, take the setTimeout out entirely. Then put these $("#dialog-modal").html('<p>Loading Complete</p>');
$('.overlay').remove();       at the very end of YOUR script as a callback function. That way, when all of your script has completed it will hide the loading dialog. :)